# Limitations to Universal Analytics using External .js

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

What are the limiations to using Universal Analytics when placed into a .js file at the  and can it result in a decrease of pageviews?

I am using the below UA code with Demographics "displayfeatures" enabled. I noticed traffic numbers declined, but I don't understand why I can't use an external .js. Any thoughts?

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'INSERT UA CODE', 'INSERT SITENAME');
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: The only compelling reason is that it's *possible* people will leave the page before your code has a chance to load and trigger if it's on the bottom. However, these days with streamlined js and much better bandwidth and computers, putting it at the bottom of the page or in an external file shouldn't give a noticeable impact. So, if you noticed a serious decline in pageviews by doing this, then your site probably has a bottleneck somewhere, e.g. some other bit of code that is taking a long time to load or hanging, longer than when  a noticeable % of your users are on a given page

Comment: Use your browser's Net/Resources tab or a Proxy/sniffer addon/program like HttpWatch or Charles Proxy or Fiddler2 to evaluate how long things are taking to load on your page

Comment: If you set up a Google Webmaster tools account you won't be able to verify the WMT account with your analytics account, and it might be that your GA account will claim that the tracking code is not installed (it will still work, though).